# Full Storage issue with second Hard Disk on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, 22.04, hard-drive, storage

I am trying to mount a second hard disk on my Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual machine to get rid of the full storage warning, but I can't seem to mount it correctly to extend the volume of the original hard disk partitions extend to the second hard disk if there is not enough room. I'm wondering if anyone knows/has steps needed to proceed with extending the volume of the second hard disk? All the tutorials/articles I found, do not work.

I'll mount it to the VM, but when I go to run `sudo apt-get update` I get the warning and I am not able to download files / programs I need to work on them because there is not enough space.

I also have been going through and deleting/removing any files or programs I don't need, but it's hardly making room.

Comment: Adding a second virtual drive to your VM will not magically provide space for adding applications. You need to go through the process of increasing the size of your original virtual drive. There are plenty of tutorials on line if you search for them. Here is just one: https://itsfoss.com/increase-disk-size-virtualbox/

Comment: To save space the steps described in this article are usually very effective https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/